# Airline Reservation System using linked list

Tags: c, file, pointers, visual-studio-2015, linked-list

Im doing airline reservation system in c programming, using linked list. It reserves a seat, views the reservation, cancels the reservation. The program runs properly for the first time without adding any data.

But when i add data and want to delete it, it gives this error "Exception thrown at 0x0FFAFBB3 (ucrtbased.dll) in ConsoleApplication1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x0004B000."

For deleting data, im comparing the phone number data. And when it compares, it deletes the record. But instead it is giving error. Anyone identify the error area and provide suggestion??

Below is the code for making reservation and deleting a reservation.

```
void new_reservation()
{
    curr = start;
    if (start == NULL)
    {
        //Empty list
        start = curr = (struct passenger *)malloc(sizeof(struct passenger));
        dataentry();
        curr->next = NULL;
        printf("\n\t Reservation successful");
        return;
    }
    //Reach end of list


    while (curr->next)
        curr = curr->next;
    curr->next = (struct passenger *)malloc(sizeof(struct passenger));
    curr = curr->next;
    dataentry();
    curr->next = NULL;
    printf("\n\t Reservation successful");
    printf("\n\t Saved to Reservation list");
}

void del()
{
    struct passenger *temp; // assigning a temporary pointer to struct airplane
    char str[20];
    printf("Enter phone number:");

    gets(str); 
    fflush(stdin);
    curr = start;
    while (curr)
    {
        if (strcmp(start->Phone, str) == 0)
        {
            temp = start;
            start = start->next;
            free(temp);
            return;
        }
        if (strcmp(curr->next->Phone, str) == 0)
        {
            temp = curr->next;
            curr->next = curr->next->next;
            free(temp);
            break;
        }
        else if (strcmp(curr->next->Phone, str) != 0)
        {
            printf("\n\n No reservations found!!");
            break;
        }
    }
    printf("\n\n Deletion successful!!");
}
```

Comment: Read [ask]. **Never ever** use `gets`. It is not part of the standard anymore for good reasons. Also `fflush(stdin);` is undefined behaviour, you can't use it like that.

Comment: `curr->next` might `NULL`.

Comment: Suggest you use a debugger to help you find the problem. Learning to effectively use a debugger is a skill well worth building up.

Comment: @kaylum i have tried using debugger, but its just giving the error i have mentioned in the question.

Comment: @Olaf what should i use instead of gets?

Comment: @bonzi If that is all you got out of the debugger then that is not *effective* use of the debugger. There is much more that you can get. For example, get the stack trace which tells you *exactly* which line triggered the crash. And then examine the variables on and around that line.

Comment: The OP needs to learn how to use a debugger before anything. spend some time learnign gdb, theres plenty of resources on youtube and google.

Comment: @tesseract sure. Ill learn it. Thanks for the suggestion. Ill look in it.

Comment: The answer to your `gets` question is just a [Google search away](https://www.google.com/search?q=what+should+i+use+instead+of+gets).

Comment: While using a debugger is definitely better, you can start with littering your code by `printf`-ing various variable values at various points in the code. (This won't always work properly, especially when using invalid pointers and such, but it's a good start.)

Comment: "what should i use instead of gets" - The obvious alternative. If you got this from a book, get a new one covering modern C. If not: get a C book, your teacher is not worth whatever he gets paid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (strcmp(start->Phone, str) == 0){...}
if (strcmp(curr->next->Phone, str) == 0){...}
else if (strcmp(curr->next->Phone, str) != 0){...}
```

This method is too complicated, it is bound to run in to errors unless you carefully check the pointers and that pointer's `next` member. You can simplify this and make only one comparison. Just make sure to keep track of the node's position, if the node being deleted is the `start` or it is another node. Example:

```
void del()
{
    char str[20];
    struct passenger *walk = start;
    if (!walk)
        return;

    printf("Enter phone number:");
    scanf("%s", str);

    struct passenger *previous = 0;
    while (walk)
    {
        if (strcmp(walk->Phone, str) == 0)
        {
            struct passenger *next = walk->next;
            free(walk);
            if (previous == 0)
            {
                //deleting the first item
                start = next;
            }
            else
            {
                //deleting an item in middle or end
                previous->next = next;
            }
            return;
        }
        previous = walk;
        walk = walk->next;
    }
}
```

`new_reservation` is probably not causing any errors, but it too can be simplified. You only need to allocate once, then insert it either at the end, or assign it as `start`. Also you can use `scanf` to read a string.

```
void new_reservation()
{
    //create new item
    curr = malloc(sizeof(struct passenger));
    curr->next = NULL;
    //I don't know this part of your code...
    dataentry(); 

    if (start == NULL)
    {
        //Empty list
        start = curr;
    }
    else
    {
        //find the end of the list
        struct passenger *walk = start;
        while (walk->next)
            walk = walk->next;
        walk->next = curr;
    }
}
```